# hubstorage import error on scrapinghub

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am getting on issue on scrapinghub during run spider , Deployment  successfully done and spider working fine on local server.

```
ImportError: No module named 'scrapinghub.hubstorage'
```

**Note :**  python3.5

**scrapinghub.yml  :**

```
projects:
  default: 123456
stacks:
  default: scrapy:1.2-py3
requirements:
  file: requirements.txt
```

**Note :**
I Installed `hubstorage` and `scrapinghub` both.

**log file :**

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 215, in main
    from sh_scrapy.writer import pipe_writer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh_scrapy/writer.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scrapinghub.hubstorage.serialization import jsondefault
```

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: Put full stack trace and also make sure it is not an issue with the version you use locally and having different version on cloud

Comment: @furas I didn't add `requirements.txt` file, otherwise i added all the informations (file including log file and scrapinghub.yml file) related to problem.(Thanks for your valuable advise)

Comment: @TarunLalwani, By default on scrapinghub spider run on python2.7, but requirements is run spider on python3.x , that's why i added dependencies on scrapinghub.yml file.
I don't think so it's version conflicts issue.
took reference from this article : https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/08/17/introducing-scrapy-cloud-with-python-3-support/

Comment: Maybe you run it on Python 3 but may be it installed modules with Python2. It would be good If you could check version `python -V` and `pip -V`. If you run code using `python script.py` then you can install module with `pyhton -m pip install module` to make sure that you install with correct python.